# MFC combobox dropdown/drop list: displaying only one item

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

I've got several comboboxes which has approx. 40 items in each of them and no matter what I've tried to set in the VS 2013 comboxbox parameter box, it still shows only one item at time. I want to show several items at one time (doesn't matter if there will be vertical scrollbar or not) right now it looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaFDh.jpg

thank you for possible ideas.

mk

Comment: possible duplicate of [MFC Combo-Box Control is not showing the full list of items when I click the drop-down menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513263/mfc-combo-box-control-is-not-showing-the-full-list-of-items-when-i-click-the-dro)

Answer (score 3):

You can change combo-box expansion area directly in dialog editor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cta1x1t.aspx